# How to find TF-IDF of specific words?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 5 text files named, 1500.txt, 1600.txt.....1900.txt. Using Python I selected 200 most frequently used words from 1500.txt and compared those words with other text files. My code is as under:-

```
common_words_1500 = Counter()

 with open('E:\\Book\\1500.txt', "r", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as File_1500:
    stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    words = word_tokenize(File_1500.read())
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in words if not w.lower() in stop_words]


for line in filtered_sentence:
    for match in re.finditer(r'\w+', line.lower()):
        word = match.group()
        st=word.strip('_')
        if len(st) > 3:
            common_words_1500[st] += 1

common_words_1600 = Counter()

 with open('E:\\Book\\1600.txt', "r", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as File_1600:
    for line in File_1600:
      for match in re.finditer(r'\w+', line.lower()):
        word = match.group()
        if len(word) > 3:
            common_words_1600[word] += 1

common_words_1700 = Counter()

 with open('E:\\Book\\1700.txt', "r", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as File_1700:
   for line in File_1700:
    for match in re.finditer(r'\w+', line.lower()):
        word = match.group()
        if len(word) > 3:
            common_words_1700[word] += 1

common_words_1800 = Counter()

 with open('E:\\Book\\1800.txt', "r", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as File_1800:
   for line in File_1800:
    for match in re.finditer(r'\w+', line.lower()):
        word = match.group()
        if len(word) > 3:
            common_words_1800[word] += 1


common_words_1900 = Counter()

 with open('E:\\Book\\1900.txt', "r", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as File_1900:
   for line in File_1900:
    for match in re.finditer(r'\w+', line.lower()):
        word = match.group()
        if len(word) > 3:
            common_words_1900[word] += 1

for (word, count) in common_words_1500.most_common(200):
   try: 
    count_in_file2 = common_words_1600[word]
    count_in_file3 = common_words_1700[word]
    count_in_file4 = common_words_1800[word]
    count_in_file5 = common_words_1900[word]

   except KeyError: 
    # if the word is not present file2_common_words,
    # then its count is 0.
    count_in_file2 = 0
    count_in_file3 = 0
    count_in_file4 = 0
    count_in_file5 = 0

print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}".format(word, count, count_in_file2,       
count_in_file3, count_in_file4, count_in_file5))
```

Now the question is, I want to calculate TF-IDF of these 200 words from each text file. I hope you all understand my question.

Comment: (1) Please provide codes with minimal details to describe your problem (2) Most frequent words strongly implies stopwords, which you don't want (3) Please google the definition of tf (term frequency) and idf (inverse document frequency) in Wikipedia. The application of the formula in your case should not be that hard.

Comment: @Mai in Wikipedia i checked the definition of TF-IDF. Sorry for detailed code. I want the number of times a word appears in the document and to find the frequency of that word. I want to remove the stop words also. If you can please help me how to apply a formula in my case. Thanks

Comment: (1) It's ok. I understand you may not be familiar with SO or Python. (2) tf is how many times a term occurs in a file (3) df is the number of files in which a term occurs (4) idf is some inverse form of df (5) tf-idf is product of tf and idf. (5) Use dictionary or counter to count what I have mentioned (6) I am not answering because this is good for you as a practice.

Comment: Ranking tf-idf will automatically filter stopwords. If you manually select most frequent words, that's another story...

Comment: @Mai thanks a lot. But i tried a lot from more than 10 days but i didn't find any way that's why i posted here to take some help. If you can correct my code then i will appreciate that most.

Comment: I am seeing just a `copy-and-paste` of answers from [Your Own Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626380/memoryerror-in-python). That's all you have done ever since `Sep 17`?