# Is regex always greedy even when I give it look ahead and look behind requirements?

Tags: python, regex, substring, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I have an `re.sub` program which substitutes certain values in between commas in `text_string`:

```
re.sub('(?:(?<=\,)|(?<=^))[^\w\d\r\n\t]*(HUN)[^\w\d\r\n\t]*(?=(?:\,|$))','',text_string,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

which replaces `HUN` with nothing.

I try this on many files.  Sometimes the files are huge, sometimes they are small.  Occasionally, I will get a `MemoryError` from the `re.py` library.  What is the best way to split up this execution so that I will not get a `MemoryError`?

I'm afraid that the regex is looking at the ENTIRE string first (e.g. in if `text_string` is `t,w,g,g,hun,t,w`), before looking between the commas, instead of just looking between the commas (i.e. in a non-greedy way).  Does anyone know how this actually gets evaluated?

If the string is super long, does the regex know to evaluate just between the commas in a non-greedy way? Thanks.

Comment: If the files are huge and you read all the data into memory then it may well simply be just because the files are huge, do you do line by line  replacing or all at once?

Comment: The files are one line long? Also, might be important to see the whole file processing routine to see how is it used. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626380/memoryerror-in-python

Comment: It's not a working pattern nor a working code.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Please take the time to reformulate your question and to clearly describe what you are trying to achieve. (with a working code that reproduces the error and an example string)

Comment: @Sother, then you must have some ridiculously long lines

Comment: Yes, these are huge csv tables.

Comment: What are you trying to replace is your pattern actually complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is really weird.

- `(?:(?<=\,)|(?<=^))` - This can be just turned into a regular non-capturing group `(?:,|^)`
- `[^\w\d]` - since `\w` already matches `\d`, `\d` is redundant
- `[^\w\r\n\t]*` - matches punctuation(!) and thus `,`, too. It makes it hard for the regex engine to analyze strings that  have many comma-separated values *before* your `hun`.
- `(?=(?:,|$))` - the lookahead make sense if you plan to match overlapping strings, otherwise, you can replace it with `(?:,|$)`.

I suggest:

```
r"(?i)(?:,|^)[^\w\r\n\t]*(HUN)[^\w\r\n\t]*(?=(?:,|$))"
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP4cM4/2)

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/Ls5knv):

```
import re
s = ",WWWWWW,hun,hun,WWWWW,"
print re.sub(r"(?i)((?:,|^)[^\w\r\n\t]*)HUN([^\w\r\n\t]*)(?=(?:,|$))", r"\1\2", s)
# => ,WWWWWW,,,WWWWW,
```

Comment: What does the `(?i)` do?

Comment: It is the `re.I` inline flag version.

Comment: Sorry for the minor typo in my question.  The `(?:(?<=\,)|(?<=\,))` should be  `(?:(?<=\,)|(?<=^))`.

Comment: Ok, then why not use a non-capturing group? It is much more efficient to use normal groups rather than alternating lookbehinds.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'll have to look those words up, sorry.  The regex you suggested does almost exactly what I need, except that it also captures, and hence substitutes the `,` on either side of `hun`.  For example,  `,hun,`  will be substituted with `''`.  Try it on : `',WWWWWW,hun,hun,WWWWW,`  and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Oh, to answer your question tho, isn't `(?:....)` a non-capturing group like I have it?

Comment: You have two lookarounds inside a non-capturing group. It makes a huge difference. What is the expected output for `,WWWWWW,hun,hun,WWWWW,`?

Comment: the expected output is simply all "hun's" removed:   `,WWWWWW,,,WWWWW,`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a faster way without regex like this:

```
s = 't,w,g,g,hun,t,w'
res = ','.join(['' if x.lower()=='hun' else x for x in s.split(',')])
```

Comment: Problem is that this won't preserve the `","`'s between huns.  e.g., try it on `"hun,hun,hun,"`".  It should return `",,,"`.

Comment: @Sother: this requirement should be in your question. In this case it's more simple.